# Symfony 3: Adding two differents entities through one controller

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony-3.4

I have 3 entities:

```php
[Formula] ----OneToMany----> [FormulaParameter] ---ManyToOne---> [Parameter]
```

I need a join table between `Formula` and `Parameter` because the relation holds information like name, value, etc.

#### Entities

```php
class Formula
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="FormulaDefinitionParameter", mappedBy="formula", cascade={"all"}, orphanRemoval=true)
     */
    private $parameters;
}
```

```php
class FormulaParameter
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Formula", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
     */
    private $formula;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Parameter")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
     */
    private $parameterFormat;

    /**
     * @var string|null
     * @ORM\Column(name="parameter_name", type="string", length=1000, nullable=true)
     */
    private $name;
}
```

#### Controller

I use only one form to add both records to the database: for structural reasons, I've chosen to retrieve the values used to fill up the `FormulaParameter` record separately and post-process the metadata in the controller.

Here a simplified version of my code:

```php
public function addFormulaAction(Request $request, $id)
{
    $session = $request->getSession();
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    if ($id) {
        $formula = $this->selectData($session, $id, "Formula");
    } else {
        $formula = new \TAMAS\AstroBundle\Entity\Formula();
    }
   
    $form = $this->get('form.factory')->create(\App\Form\FormulaType::class, $formulaDefinition);

    if ($request->isMethod('POST') && $form->handleRequest($request)->isValid()) {
        // METADATA RETRIEVAL
        $params = $form->get('parameter')->getData();
        foreach ($params as $id => $param){
            // CREATION OF THE FORMULA PARAMETER
            $paramFormula = new E\FormulaParameter();
            $paramFormula->setParameterFormat($em->find("Parameter", $id));
            if (isset($param["name"]) && $param["name"]){
                $paramFormula->setName($param["name"]);
            }
            $paramFormula->setFormula($formula);
            // ADDITION OF THE FORMULA PARAMETER TO THE DATABASE
            $em->persist($paramFormula);
            $em->flush();
        }

        // ADDITION OF THE FORMULA TO THE DATABASE
        $em->persist($formula);
        $em->flush();
        
        return $this->redirectToRoute('home');
    }

    return $this->render('addFormula.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
        'formula' => $formula
    ));
}
```

As you can see, what I want to achieve is to **add 2 records from different entities to the database in the same controller**. I've tried several thing but none of it is working. Usually the error triggered is something like:

`An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO formula_parameter (...) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)' with params [...]`

Do you have any idea how I could do that?

#### Environment

```
Symfony version: 3.4.3
PHP version: 7.2.24
Firefox / Ubuntu 10.15.5
```

Comment: Start with the obvious: does dd($params); verify that $params has the expected values?  If so then does $em->find("Parameter", $id) work as expected?  You have some rather strange looking code (as compared to what is in the Symfony docs) so all you can really do is to go step by step and verify things are properly working.

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve to add a `ParameterFormula` through the `Formula` Form Controller, I only had to add a `addParameter()` method to the `Formula` entity like so:

```php
/**
 * Add parameter
 * @param FormulaParameter $parameter
 * @return Formula
 */
public function addParameter(FormulaParameter $parameter)
{
    $this->parameters->add($parameter);
    return $this;
}
```

And then use this method inside the Controller:

```php
foreach ($params as $id => $param){
    // CREATION OF THE FORMULA PARAMETER
    $paramFormula = new E\FormulaParameter();
    $paramFormula->setParameter($em->find("Parameter", $id));
    if (isset($param["name"]) && $param["name"]){
          $paramFormula->setName($param["name"]);
    }
    $paramFormula->setFormula($formula);
    // ADDITION TO THE FORMULA PARAMETER
    $formula->addParameter($paramFormula);
}
```